# How to Circulate Token in a network from one peer to another?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I am creating a token contract and try to ciruculate that token in other peers, how could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a token contract on the public Ethereum blockchain, it is automatically "circulated" to all full Ethereum nodes. When I say this, I mean that all nodes that are keeping up w/ the current blockchain will download your contract (and run it, if there are transactions that run it) if it is published on the blockchain.

In that sense, when you publish a contract, you can treat this "publishing" as a normal transaction (to some degree). Sure you have to write the contract's code and compile it, but you don't have to do anything special to make sure it gets to all the nodes. In this sense, it is the same as an average Ether transfer transaction.